# How to bind a DataGridComboBoxColumn outside the ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I am working on my first 'production' WPF app, and I'm encountering an issue.
I have some code that is similar to the example below.  The problem I am having is that I cannot get the `ComboBox` to populate.  I'm assuming it is because the `Grid`'s `ItemsSource` is 'blocking' the `ComboBox`from being able to see the Tasks collection on the ViewModel, but I am only guessing.  Everything else is databinding correctly.

I scoured SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497113/c-wpf-binding-combobox-itemsource-in-datagrid-to-element-outside-of-the-datacon) question; which sounds exactly like what I am trying to do, but it did not work for me.

Any idea why I can't get the `ComboBox` to populate?

Model:

```
public class Activity{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public Task Task { get; set; }
}

public class Task{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public ApprovalViewModel{
  public ObservableCollection<Activity> Activities { /* ... property logic */ }
  public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { /* ... property logic */ }
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="displayTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Task.Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="editTemplate">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" <!--I think the problem is here-->
              SelectedValue="{Binding Task}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding User}" Header="User"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Task.Project.Title}" Header="Project"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn 
            Header="Task" 
            CellTemplate="{StaticResource displayTemplate}" 
            CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource editTemplate}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Edit:** the correct `ComboBox` code is here:

```
<ComboBox 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Tasks, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
  SelectedValue="{Binding Task.Title}"
  SelectedValuePath="Title"
  DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in where the problem lies, that binding is relative to the `Activity`. So it is looking for `Activity.Tasks`.

The post you linked to has the right approach, you just need to tweak it for your situation.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Tasks, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

This will go back up the Visual tree looking for a Window, which has a `DataContext.Tasks` property.

Is your code example inside a window? If not you will need to change the {x:Type } and secondly is the `DataContext` set on this object? If not you will need to set it to your ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! I had to set the x:Type to UserControl.  Also I was confused (and still am), because the FindAncestor does not show up in Intellisense.  It seems to work though.